# Probability of Hits

Tags: probability

I went on vacation recently. When I left my favorite baseball player had $138$ hits in $423$ at bats for a batting average of $.326$. He had played in $110$ games so far. I was gone for $12$ days, and the team played a game everyday. When I came back, his batting average was $.309$ What was his probable batting average for the games that I missed? (Assume he played in every game.)

If you are gone for $12$ days and the baseball player plays every game then he plays a total of $122$ games. If his average goes to $.309$ from $.326$, what am I trying to find? And how do I find it? I think that if he has hit $138$ out of $423$ in $110$ games means for every game there is about $3.84$ hits. So for $122$ games ($+12$ games) I multiplied $3.84\cdot 12$ games $= 46.08$ more hits. When I added that to $423$ It equaled about $469$ rounded. Then I found for his batting average to equal $.309$ he would have to have $7$ hits out of those $12$ games - $\frac{145}{469} = .309$ ... Would this be the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So he has an average of $$\frac{423}{110}$$ at bats per game. In twelve games that is $$AB=12\left(\frac{423}{110}\right)$$ Let's say he got $H$ hits of those $AB$ at bats. Then his new batting average would be $$\frac{138+H}{423+AB}=.309$$ This gives $$H=.309(423+AB)-138$$ So $$\text{Batting Average over 12 days}=\frac{H}{AB}=\frac{.309(423+AB)-138}{AB}$$ where $AB$ is given in the second equation.

Incidentally, a fraction analysis shows that the only possible fraction with a denominator around 470 is 
$$\frac{145}{469}=0.3091684434968017$$ so $$H=145-138=7,\hspace{2mm}AB=469-423=46,\hspace{2mm}\frac{H}{AB}=.152$$ were the actual statistics in real life.

Comment: So his probable batting average is 145/469? Not the 7 hits out of 12 games.

Comment: He hit .152 over the games you missed. 145/469 is the batting average for the whole season.